# Change color of __init__ and other predefined items in Pycharm's syntax highlighting

Tags: python, pycharm, syntax-highlighting, color-blindness

I'm colorblind and I can barely make out the `__init__` when it is on the current line where the caret is, as in this example:

[image]

I just can't see it against that highlighted "caret line" background. Same problem for `__repr__`, `__str__`, and other such predefined items.

So, I'd like to change their color. How do I do that?

I looked through the color settings (pic below), but I can't figure out which one to change. None of them seem to do what I want.

[image]

Yes, I know I could change the color of 'caret row', but that's not a viable alternative, because `__init__`'s current color also gives me problems in other circumstances.

Comment: You may like to know that there are [websites](http://color-themes.com/?view=index) where you are able to download different themes for Pycharm so you may be able to just find one that suits your needs easier than manually editing the scheme

Comment: @Sayse: I think that's great advice. For sure there must be color schemes designed for the most common forms of color blindness.

Comment: True. But there's a baby & bathwater aspect to this, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PyCharm you can go to File > Settings...

In the settings panel you can go to Editor > Colors and Fonts and select Python.

Now you are given a ***code sample*** where `__init__` is probably part of. If you **click on the `__init__` element**, PyCharm will redirect you to an element called "*Predefined item definition*" which you can set to another color (the "Foreground" element in the right panel):

[image]

This is a screenshot of Pycharm Community on Ubuntu. I hope this helps.

Your settings panel seems to have a hierarchical view, based on the panel on the right it is probably located under **Identifiers > Predefined symbol**.

Changing this will change all predefined elements (like `__len__`, `__class__`, etc.) but since you say it is because of color blindness, you want probably to change these as well anyway.